# Establish relationship between two Jenkins Jobs available on different Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I am building Jenkins for Test / QA automation scripts, lets name it TEST_JOB. For application, I have application source code Jenkins build, name it DEV_JOB.

My scenario is when DEV_JOB completes execution (successfully), execute TEST_JOB immediately. I am aware about setting up project upstream / downstream [ *Build after other projects are built* ] to accomplish this task. But here, Problem is DEV_JOB is on different server than TEST_JOB. Due to which, TEST_JOB fails to recognize DEV_JOB.

Now, how would I achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jenkins API for remote trigger of Job.
Say you have job on DEV_JOB on JENKINS_1, add a penultimate step(or upstream/downstream project having only this step) which invokes TEST_JOB using remote API call of JENKINS_2 server.
Example command would be

`$(curl --user "username:password" "http://JENKINS_2/job/TEST_JOB/buildWithParameters?SOMEPARAMETER=$SOMEPARAMETER")`

**username:password** is a valid user on JENKINS_2. 
Avoid using your own account here but rather a 'build trigger' account that only has permissions to start those jobs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get a better understanding on subject but don't know how to do it exactly. I checked option `Trigger builds remotely` for TEST_JOB and passed Authentication token like `localhost:8080/job/TEST_JOB/buildWithParameters?projectsToWatch=DEV_JOB`. How exactly do i need to move forward from here?